# ChartJs days of the week from numbers

Tags: chart.js

I have a chart were the data looks like this where **X** represents days of the week:

```
{x: 1, y: 18, r: 4.7614}
{x: 6, y: 17, r: 4.7619}
{x: 0, y: 16, r: 4.7657}
```

[image]

**I'd like to rename the numbers to weekdays on the X axis (0: "Sunday", 1: "Monday") etc., but I can't figure it out.**

My config looks like this: (but obviously not working).
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
const config = {
    type: "bubble",
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        x: ["Sun", "Mon", "Thu", "Wen", "Tru", "Fri", "Sat"],
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tickCallback to transform the value to whatever you like, easyest thing to do is make an array with all the weekDays and then use the value as an index like so:

```js
const weekDays = ["Sun", "Mon", "Thu", "Wen", "Tru", "Fri", "Sat"];

const options = {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 1,
        r: 4
      }, {
        x: 1,
        y: 1,
        r: 4
      }, {
        x: 2,
        y: 1,
        r: 4
      }, {
        x: 3,
        y: 1,
        r: 4
      }, {
        x: 4,
        y: 1,
        r: 4
      }, {
        x: 5,
        y: 1,
        r: 4
      }, {
        x: 6,
        y: 1,
        r: 4
      }],
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          callback: (val) => (weekDays[val])
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```